# Bash when piping colored keyword grep to file it doesn't hold the color

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to grep a file and highlight keywords with color and then output the beautify output to either replace the file or output to a new file.

My file gets generated correctly `user.log` and when I run this:

```
grep --color -E -i "Error|$" user.log
```

I see the correct output on the terminal. However, when I try to output to a file like this:

```
grep --color -E -i "Error|$" user.log > user_pretty.log
```

the color options disappear (contents are still there but just black and white).

Another thing is when I try to output and replace the file like this `grep --color -E -i "Error|$" user.log > user.log` The contents disappear (when I run `cat` it is just blank).

Am I not allowed to direct the output to a new file with color options?

Comment: You want `--color=always`. The default meaning of `--color` is `--color=auto`, which turns off when output is not to a TTY.

Comment: when you redirect the output, only output text is redirected. Colors are applied by your terminal program and they cannot be redirected. Plus, a log file is a plain text file. A plain text file can only keep text and nothing else.

Comment: @sid-m, colors are in general written to the terminal through the same streams (stdout/stderr) as other content, so it's not that the control sequences used to set them can't be redirected; it's just that well-behaved programs are expected to turn them off when not writing to a device that can render them, unless the user **explicitly** requests otherwise.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy even if we somehow manage to redirect them, the actual characters corresponding to those sequences will be redirected to the file, and not the actual colors. A plain text file is just plain text, it cannot contain colors or formatting.

Comment: @sid-m, ...it can "contain colors" every bit as much as a program's output can "contain colors" in any other sense, which is to say, it can contain output that tells a terminal (of the type currently given in the `TERM` variable) to render surrounding content in color when said output is written to same. Trying to distinguish between those cases strikes me as an exercise in sophistry.

Comment: @sid-m, ...in terms of what "a plain text file" can contain, the POSIX standard specifies that a text file must (1) consist of lines, each of which ends with a carriage return, and (2) not contain any literal NULs. There are no NULs in control sequences for any terminal I'm aware of (particularly as NULs were historically used as a no-op / delay characters with historical terminals getting their input from a physical serial line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--color` (assuming GNU `grep`, but probably similarly for other versions of `grep` supporting color) is short for `--color=auto`, which means the output only contains the appropriate escape sequences if `grep` determines its standard output is a terminal. To force color when writing to a file, use `--color=always`.

(What you use to *view* the file may or may not interpret those bytes as you expect. `cat user_pretty.log` will just write everything to the terminal, which will interpret them the same as if you had just run `grep` without redirection. If you open the file in an editor, you will *probably* see the editor's representation of non-printable characters.)